# Graylog2 - Grouping on host name variants

Tags: reporting, graylog

We are sending Apache access logs to Graylog (2.1.1). We have 70+ websites and I want to build a quick value chart for say all requests that resulted in a 5xx response.
Currently when I create said chart www.somedomain.com and somedomain.com are treated separately, I want to combine the count for those 2 variants of the same site. So if the counts for 5xx errors were:
www.somesite.com 10
somesite.com 5
www.someother.com 3
someother.com 4
The quick chart would would have the following:
somesite.com 15
someother.com 7

How can I achieve that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your SEO department should yell at you for not doing a 301 on the root to www. domain....which would also fix the issue.

Comment: Actually it looks like we should be doing the reverse by way of a rule in our Varnish VCL:
if ( req.http.Host ~ "^www\.") {
        return (synth(301, req.http.Host));
    }
But I've yet to dig into that and if true why it's not doing it for all requests, but that's another story. ;)

Comment: lol that's a mistake but you'll figure that out another day.

Comment: I've no doubt, I'm uncovering a lot of mistakes as I dig deeper into this environment.

Comment: ansible galaxy can help a lot

Answer (score 1):

you could add a grok filter like `www.%{HOST}|%{HOST}` as an extractor to split out a new value to "site_hostname" and then use that to filter.